# How to get year and quarter for sysdate in Oracle Sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to get the quarter and year depending on the sysdat in Oracle sql.
For example i want expected  result value as `2022q3` for current quarter.

I can get the quarter using below query:

```
select to_char(sysdate, 'Q') as qtr from  dual;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with the format string `'YYYY"Q"Q'`:

```
select to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY"Q"Q') as qtr
from dual
```

A possible way to get previous quarter:

```
select to_char(sysdate - interval '3' month, 'YYYY"Q"Q') as qtr
from dual
```

Comment: one question what if i want to subtract the qurter how to do that ? So for example the query should result 2022q3 as the quarter q4 has not finished